# Can you permanently disable auto-calculate on specific sheets in a excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large excel workbook that has 23 sheets currently. The workbook takes about 100k lines of inventory and sorts it into 8 of the worksheets by inventory location, the other 15 sheets are used to tally numbers and move inventory as need. The 100k inventory is sorted by the 8 inventory sheets using around 400 sumifs and countifs formulas per sheet totaling around 3200 formulas. My workbook is starting to get serious lag as every time data is changed on one of the 15 working sheets the 8 inventory sheets recalculate. To breakdown what I am trying to find out, I need 15 sheets set to auto-calculate and 8 sheets set to manual calculate at the same time. Is there anyway to do this.  I have not included any code as this is a excel functionality question. I have searched extensively but all the literature I can find says that with the calculate function it is a all or nothing situation. But before rewriting the entire workbook to switch all the formula to VBA I thought I would see if anyone has found a work around.

Comment: It's a workbook setting, so can't be set for individual sheets. I have a similar issue for some of my data handling. My solution is that I have two workbooks. The first is purely data and lookups that don't have any real calculation time. The second workbook, I have linked worksheets to pull data from the first workbook, then other worksheets with large calculations. The workbook is set to manual calculation and recalculate on close. Normally, I just open and close the workbook then it saves which takes around 15 minutes. The first workbook can then pull back data from the second.

Comment: I had it originally set it up that way but it turned out to be a bigger mess than what I have now. I have to send copies of the workbook out to other departments to use and although I maybe able to operate it with no issues, other not so savvy individuals have a tendence to break it. Lol, I had to trouble shoot one copy that some how, the individual couldn't explain it, had what was a link between to cells now hyperlinked to a cornbread receipt online and the workbook was still password locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need VBA to do this.

1. Disable auto-calculation and calculate on save; this can be done in Excel or VBA with:

   ```
   Application.Calculation = xlManual, Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
   ```
2. Make a list of all the sheets you want to "auto-calculate"
3. Loop through the list, use `Worksheets(1).Calculate` or `Sheets("Sheet1").Calculate` to calculate a single sheet at a time
4. You can set this to run every time you make a change in your notebook with the `Worksheet.Change` event, or personally I would make a button that runs the macro when clicked.

A quick prototype:

```vb
Sub customcalc  
 Dim myarray As Variant  
 myarray = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")  
 For Each s In myarray  
  Sheets(s).Calculate  
 Next s  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a quick simple work around. I have added it to a module and call it with each of the sheets I want to calculate.